# Upgrade from Wagtail 2.15.6 to Wagtail 4.2.2 - Reports / Workflow error

Tags: django-models, wagtail

We have upgraded from wagtail 2.15.6 to wagtail 4.2.2, everything is working now apart from Reports / Workflows and Reports / Workflow tasks

Getting error

```
env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1955, in add_fields

    join_info = self.setup_joins(name.split(LOOKUP_SEP), opts, alias, allow_many=allow_m2m)

AttributeError: 'Cast' object has no attribute 'split'
```

If I debug in 2.15.6 name is such as 'requested__pk' whereas in 4.2.2 it is Cast(F('id'))

???

Thanks

Comment: As per https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/upgrading.html#upgrade-process, it's recommended to upgrade one point release at a time, rather than going straight from 2.x to 4.x.

Comment: I have now upgraded our dev to 3.0.3 and all works fine, however I would like to try 4.0.4 but having trouble with pip-compile and compatible versions of wagtailmedia and wagtailmodel-translation

Comment: I upgraded to 4.0.4 successfully all works fine then I upgraded to 4.1.5 no errors but edit pages has no content